# Why does this seem like a strange way of connecting a bridge circuit to the ADC?

Tags: adc, schematics, load-cell, strain-gage

I was planning to hook up a quarter bridge circuit to the [AD7730LBR](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7730_7730L.pdf) Analogue to Digital Converter that I bought. I was having a look at a "Load_Cell_Schematic" provided by [this](http://www.osengr.org/Projects/Load-Cell-Shield/Load-Cell-Shield.html) webpage (the download link is at the bottom of the webpage) where they connected a load cell to the same chip.

As you can see the Output- terminal of the load cell is going to AINI- and AINI2+ of the ADC while Output+ of the cell is going to AINI+ and AINI2- of the ADC. I was going through the ADC’s datasheet and based on my understanding you can either use AINI+ and AINI- pair or AINI2+ and AINI2- pair of the ADC to connect to the output voltage terminals of a bridge circuit or a load cell.

The diagram at page 40 of the datasheet also supports my understanding and I could not find any diagram supporting the wiring shown in the schematic of the webpage. So any ideas what is going on in the schematic and if yes how does that affect the programming of the AINI pins of the ADC?

Comment: May be they are doing this for redundancy, if in case channel 1 is having some issue, you can try routing the input to channel 2 and check the output.

Comment: I see. But am I right in my description of how it should be connected then?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes as per the datasheet page 40, I think you are correct. And even the ADC is single channel with MUX is just to make it dual input.